# ActiveJDBC: Joined rows of findBySQL with join are empty

Tags: java, orm, activejdbc

I am performing a mildly complex query in a `findBySQL` call with ActiveJDBC. I receive results as expected, but when I query joind rows with `getAll`, the results are empty.

```
List<ClassSession> classSessions = ClassSession.findBySQL("""
        select class_sessions.*
        from class_sessions
                 join class_session_lesson_times on class_sessions.id = class_session_lesson_times.class_session_id
                 join class_session_lesson_instructors on class_session_lesson_times.id = class_session_lesson_instructors.class_session_lesson_time_id
        where class_session_lesson_instructors.instructor_id = ?
        order by class_session_lesson_times.lesson_time_epochms desc
        """, user.getPersonId()).include(ClassSessionLessonTime.class);
List<ClassSessionLessonTime> lts = classSessions.get(0).getAll(ClassSessionLessonTime.class);
List<ClassSessionLessonTime> lts2 = ClassSession.findBySessionSerialized(classSessions.get(0).getSessionSerialized()).getAll(ClassSessionLessonTime.class);
```

When this finishes, `lts` is empty, and `lts2` has 18 elements (which is what I expected).

I think the presence of the `join`s in the `findBySQL` query interferes with the population of the `cachedChildren` field in `Model.java`, but I don't know how resolve this. I know I could make a `Base.find()` call and parse results by hand but this seems like a lot of work I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Can you please post your table structure?

Comment: ClassSession is 1:* to ClassSessionLessonTime. ClassSessionLessonTime is 1:1 to ClassSessionLessonInstructor.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround:

```java
List<ClassSession> classSessions = Base.findAll("""
    select class_sessions.*
    from class_sessions
             join class_session_lesson_times on class_sessions.id = class_session_lesson_times.class_session_id
             join class_session_lesson_instructors on class_session_lesson_times.id = class_session_lesson_instructors.class_session_lesson_time_id
    where class_session_lesson_instructors.instructor_id = ?
    order by class_session_lesson_times.lesson_time_epochms desc
    """, user.getPersonId())
.stream()
.map(row -> (ClassSession) new ClassSession().fromMap(row))
.toList();
```

The original issue seems like a gotcha but this solution works for me. Open to better solutions.

Comment: it is unlikely that the join wold have an effect on cached children. In any case, your solution can be wrapped inside an accessor method in the class ClassSession for cleaner code. If you create a simple project on Github that reproduces this issue, I can tinker and find the exact reason. In any case, there are many ways to kill a cat with JavaLite :)

Comment: You're right - when I tried to build a repro I realised a crucial mistake I made in my code. In my original code where I had this problem, I had `select *` but in my code above I have `select class_sessions.*`. The latter works fine. Sorry to waste your time!

Comment: Glad it worked out for  you!